# Conditional compilation:initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have to assign a variable to a constant like this (the code below is at the beginning of my file code, before `@implementation`):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
NSString *hostStr=[[NSString alloc]init];
hostStr=@"xxx.mycompany.com";
static NSString * const host = hostStr;
#endif
```

If i do like so:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
static NSString * const host = @"xxx.mycompany.com";
#endif
```

That will work.

Actually, in my real case, `host` will contain the value of a global value (declared in the app delegate and initialized in another view controller). But for the sake of simplifying my problem, i use this example (since both cases give me the same error).

How can i fix this problem please. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Constants that are set **outside** of any function cannot be "dynamic".  This means that the compiler has to know what the constant value is before the program is run.  If you say something like this:

```
static int x = myFunction(459);
```

The compiler can't know what myFunction() will return until the program is actually run.

This is why:

```
NSString *hostStr=[[NSString alloc]init];
```

causes a syntax error.  The compiler **will not** execute any code when making a constant.

---

The solution is simple:

```
NSString *host=@"www.mycompany.com";
```

Notice that I didn't use the "static" qualifier.  That would make "host" only available to the code in the file it was declared it.  Dropping the "static" qualifier makes it global.

To access this global variable from another file, the other file needs to declare

```
extern NSString *host;
```

at which point the other file will be able to see the contents of "host".

Another thing to point out, is that this:

```
NSString *hostStr=[[NSString alloc]init];
hostStr=@"xxx.mycompany.com";
```

doesn't really do much.  You create an NSString with alloc/init, then immediately assign
a constant to it, moving the NSString you created aside, without disposing of it, creating a memory leak.  (If you have ARC enabled, then it's a non-issue.  ARC knows all.)